# Benq 5150C scanning 1/4 of page

Tags: drivers, scanner, sane

I have a Benq 5150C scanner. It didn't work out of the box.

After downloading the windows driver (from Benq Middle East), extracting the .bin file and following this post, the scanner started working but only scanning 1/4 of the page. It seems there's a problem with resolution.

Is there a way to configure it to work properly?

Using Ubuntu 14.04 64 bit.